# How to setup birthdate field with optional values

Tags: 7, datetime

I want to have a "birthdate" field for my users. It should be optional to enter a year or a date.
If a year is selected I want to display the age. If a date is entered I want to show the birthdate.

If I use the date field and make it optional I can have empty default values. However, as soon as I enter a year it requires the date and month too and vise versa.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define 3 optional selects:
 - Year (`now()` to `now()` - 100)
 - Month (1-12)
 - Day (1-31)

Then in a [hook_node_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) I would check if only the year is provided or a full date. Also don't forget to verify if the date is valid (like Feb, 31...) using [`checkdate( int $month , int $day , int $year )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php).

Then create a [field template](http://drupal.org/node/1089656#field-suggestion) to either display the age or a birthdate.